# SQL get results where column values have same value in other column

Tags: sql

Hello guys I can not figure out how to write query which would return results where which provider ids are assigned to all operator ids.

```
 operatorid-providerid
1     [1]  - [3]   
2     [2]  - [1]  
3     [3]  - [2]   
4     [1]  - [3]   
5     [2]  - [2]   
6     [3]  - [1]   
7     [1]  - [2]   
8     [2]  - [3]   
9     [3]  - [1]   
10    [1]  - [5]
11    [2]  - [5]
```

Expected result :

```
       operator-provider
    1     [1]  - [3]   
    2     [2]  - [1]  
    3     [3]  - [2]   
    4     [1]  - [3]   
    5     [2]  - [2]   
    6     [3]  - [1]   
    7     [1]  - [2]   
    8     [2]  - [3]   
    9     [3]  - [1]
```

providerid 5 is not shown because it was not assigned to operatorid 3

I have tried many options but with no success here is last query. I would post code but it won't make sense.

Code :

```
SELECT t2.operatoriausID,t2.papildomosPaslaugosID
FROM OperatoriausPapildomaPaslauga t2,
(SELECT t5.papildomosPaslaugosID,count(t5.papildomosPaslaugosID) c
FROM OperatoriausPapildomaPaslauga t5
group by t5.papildomosPaslaugosID) d
WHERE d.c = 3
```

Comment: Is that one column? operator-provider? or two separate columns?

Comment: This website is for programmers to help other programmers, so it's hard to believe that we won't understand or make sense of your code.

Comment: @ub3rst4r I understand

Comment: This is 2 seperate columns

Comment: @Bensinaspa, are there always 3 operators? 1 has no 1, 3 has no 3. why are they on the result?

Comment: @ub3rst4r code added.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri yes but I don't want to use input values like 1 2 or 3. I need to use code if table values are changed.

Comment: @Bensinaspa, what rdbms you use?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri becouse I need to see results operators with containing providers. But only those providers who has 1 2 3 operators. Operator 3 does not have provider 5.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri sql server 2008

Comment: @Bensinaspa Did you notice you have a posted answer that I am pretty sure it correct.  Why don't you test it rather than spend time on comments.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I am on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte1 as 
(  select distinct(operatorid) from table ) 
,    cte2 as 
(  select providerid 
     from table 
     join cte1 
       on cte1.operatorid = table.operatorid 
    group by providerid 
   having count(distinct(table.operatorid)) = ( select count(*) from cte1 )
)
select table.* 
  from table 
  join cte2 
    on table.providerid = cte2.providerid
```

or this maybe even works

```
select table.* 
  from table 
  join ( select providerid 
           from table 
          group by providerid 
         having count(distinct(operatorid)) = ( select count(distinct(operatorid)) 
                                                  from table )
       ) tt
    on table.providerid = tt.providerid
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but having count have mistake in it

Comment: providerid.operatorid is invalid

Comment: it shoud be table.operatorid. But thanks your answer helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

```
select table.*
from table
where table.providerID in (
    select table.providerID
    from table
    group by table.providerID
    having count(distinct table.operatorID) = 
         (select count(distinct table.operatorID) 
          from table)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `not exists` predicate:

```
with cte as(select distinct(operatorid) o from table)
select * from table t1
where not exists(select * from cte c 
                 left join table t2 on c.o = t2.operatorid and 
                                       t1.providerid = t2.providerid 
                 where t2.providerid is null)
```